# c programm work different ways but i didn't change it

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, void, void-pointers

I haved to realise dynamic array in c. Here is the struct of it:

```c
typedef void (*PrintArrayElement)(const void* element);

typedef struct {
    size_t size;
    size_t capacity;
    void** array;
    PrintArrayElement printElement;  // Callback
} dynamic_array;
```

I have realised function to add element to array:

```c
void arrayAddItem(dynamic_array* container, void* item)
{
    if (container->size == container->capacity)
    {
        void** temp = container->array;
        container->capacity <<= 1;
        container->array = (void **)realloc(container->array, container->capacity * sizeof(void*));
        if (!container->array)
        {
            printf("Out of Memory\n");
            container->array = temp;
            return;
        }
    }
    container->array[container->size] = strdup(item);
    container->size++;
}
```

Also I have function to find word indexes in string:

```c
dynamic_array* findWord(char str[], char keyword[])
{
    dynamic_array* indexes;
    arrayInit(&indexes, 16, printInt);
    int i = 0;
    int start = 0;
    int end = 0;
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    while (i < len) {
        while (i < len && !isalpha(str[i]))
        {
            i++;
        }
        if (isalpha(str[i]))
        {
            start = i;
            while (i < len && isalpha(str[i]))
            {
                i++;
            }
            end = i;
            char* word = (char*)malloc(end - start + 1);
            strncpy(word, &str[start], end - start);
            word[end - start] = '\0';
            if(strcmp(word, keyword) == 0)
            {
                printf("%d\n", start);
                arrayAddItem(indexes, &start);
            }
            free(word);
        }
    }
    return indexes;
}
```

So I write `dynamic_array* test_find_array1 = findWord("hello, world, hello", "hello");` and waiting for dynamic_array with two elements: 0 and 14, but I have a dynamic_array with pointers. And the main problem is that sometimes I have the correct answer, but I didn't rewrite the code. Why can it happen?

I tried to rewrite findWord function and arrayAddItem but its still going random way. I have nothing ideas whats wrong. Let me know if I should add some code of other functions from project.

Comment: "sometimes I have the correct answer" tends to mean you've hit undefined behavior...

Comment: Why are you using `void*`?

Comment: [Should I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/should-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: This line `arrayInit(&indexes, 16, printInt);` isn't compilable with the given code. And later, `container->capacity <<= 1;` apparently had no value set.

Comment: `arrayAddItem(indexes, &start);` You're passing a pointer to an integer to the function, and inside the function there's `strdup(item)` which expects a nul terminated string. How is that supposed to work? Also, if the out of memory condition inside the add function is ever hit the capacity will be incorrect since it was already modified.

Comment: This looks fairly pointless. If the code works, a "word" only qualifies to be registered in the list if it matches the keyword exactly... A simple counter could achieve the same result.

Comment: @WeatherVane I have to do a polymorph dynamic array. I know that we havent OOP programming in C but my university doesnt think so

Comment: @RetiredNinja Big thanks! I changed strdup to memcpy and it works! Sorry if this was stupid question but I actually hadn't noticed that

Comment: It's way more helpful if you provide a program instead of incomplete snippets.

Comment: strdup() may fail, arrayAddItem will fail if capacity of container is 0.

Comment: How do you know how much memory to copy with memcpy (instead of strdup)?

Comment: If arrayAddItem fails it's capacity on realloc it's capacity will be wrong.  If it fails on strdup the last array element will be NULL.

Comment: @AllanWind Full code of programm is big, I cant show all here. By the way, thanks for your comments, I'm not very experienced with C, hadn't thought about some of the issues. The way I allocate memory with memcpy is like this: 
```c
void* item_copy = malloc(sizeof(void*));
    memcpy(item_copy, item, sizeof(void*));
    container->array[container->size] = item_copy;
```

Comment: An important part of asking for help is to provide a [mre].  You already use `realloc()` to make space for the pointer so I doubt you need to do another `malloc()`.

Comment: `void* item_copy = malloc(sizeof(void*)); ` is totally wrong, and only "works" by sheer luck. You don't know how to copy an element. Maybe it is an integer? Maybe it is a string? Maybe it is another dynamic array? Your `dynamic_array` struct should contain a *function* that allocates and copies an element, just like it contains a function that prints an element (and also a function that deallocates an element).

Comment: (contd) We say that your array *owns* the elements. It allocates them. deallocates them, and copies them as needed. Another way of handling this task is to have an array that doesn't own its elements but only stores pointers to element the user owns and gives to it. This way you don't need additional functions, and you do not allocate or copy elements. You just assign pointers. That is, instead of the three lines you give in the comment, you just use `container->array[container->size] = item;` (no malloc, no memcpy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should provide a minimal reproducible example program that demonstrate the issue.  From the question headers are missing as are the implementations of `arrayInit()`, `printInt()` and `main()`.  Presumably a `arrayFree()` is also missing otherwise your program leaks memory.  I added example implementations for you to test your code.  `printElement` is not used so you should eliminate it.
2. `arrayAddItem()` will fail if `capacity` is initialized to `0`.  You expect memory to be allocated but isn't.  `malloc(0)` is implementation defined and could be NULL which now runs afoul of check if `realloc()` failed.  I added a check and default to `capacity = 1` if it was `0`.  It's not wrong to use `<<1` but `* 2` probably compiles to the same thing and easier to read at lest to me.

   The factor `2` is fine for small values but `2^capacity` grows fast. Say, you have `2^10` elements (i.e. 8 MB to store void pointers) do you want want to allocate another 8 MB when you hit that?

   Also it's an optimization so you could see (benchmark) what the overhead is for growing 1 element at a time before doing so in batches.  `malloc()` may have similar optimizations, or others that result in batches being both slower and wasteful of memory.
3. (not fixed) `arayAddItem()`: `capacity` could overflow which result in data loss when `array` shrinks.
4. `arrayAddItem()` uses `strdup()` to copy `item` which means it assumes a string.  In `findWord()` you pass in `int` so this will most likely segfault.  Changing the API to expect caller to provide a copy of the data and caller is also responsible for free'ing said data (for symmetry).  Otherwise you need to tell `arrayAddItem()` how to copy (i.e. size) whatever `item` points to.
5. `arrayAddItem()` will return an invalid `container->capacity` if `realloc()` fails (new capacity instead of the old capacity).   I updated code to use variables and only update `container` upon success to illustrate it (they are not actually used as the program will now exit on failure).
6. `arrayAddItem()` error handling strategy is inconsistent.  You ignore the possibility of `strdup()` failing and return corrupt data if `realloc()` fail.  You don't check if `arrayInit()` fails so I assume you don't return anything.  Now code `exit(1)` upon failure.  API needs to change to survive these errors but if you are out of memory you probably will quit anyways.
7. (not fixed) `findWord()` will fail if either `str` or `keyword` is NULL.  You could use `assert()` if it's a error, or you need a check if it's valid run-time condition that you need to handle.
8. `findWord()`: minimize scope of variables and avoid the `start = 0` and `end = 0` which initial values art not used.
9. `findWord()`: `strlen()` returns a `size_t` but you use `int` for `start`, `end` and `i`.  Prefer unsigned types.
10. `findWord()`: It's silly to go through all that effort to copy the string if you only want to record the starting position.  The main thing is that you want to `malloc` space for the position so you can pass a pointer to `arrayAddItem()`.  (As an exercise try pass `&start` to see why that won't work).
11. (not fixed) `findWord()`: strings contain a terminating `\0`.  It's common idiom for c code to rely on that instead of calculating the length of a string.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    size_t size;
    size_t capacity;
    void** array;
} dynamic_array;

void arrayInit(dynamic_array **container, size_t capacity)
{
    *container = malloc(sizeof **container);
    if(!*container)
    {
        printf("malloc failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    (*container)->size = 0;
    (*container)->capacity = capacity;
    (*container)->array = capacity ? malloc(sizeof *(*container)->array * capacity) : NULL;
    if(capacity && !(*container)->array)
    {
        printf("malloc of array failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}

void arrayFree(dynamic_array *container) {
    if(!container) return;
    free(container->array);
    free(container);
}

void arrayAddItem(dynamic_array* container, void* item) {
    if (container->size == container->capacity)
    {
        size_t new_capacity = container->capacity ? container->capacity * 2 : 1;
        void **new_array = realloc(container->array, sizeof *(container->array) * new_capacity);
        if(!new_array)
        {
            printf("malloc failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        container->capacity = new_capacity;
        container->array = new_array;
    }
    container->array[container->size] = item;
    container->size++;
}

dynamic_array* findWord(char str[], char keyword[]) {
    dynamic_array* indexes;
    arrayInit(&indexes, 0);
    size_t i = 0;
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    size_t keyword_len = strlen(keyword);
    while (i < len) {
        while (i < len && !isalpha(str[i]))
            i++;
        if (isalpha(str[i]))
        {
            size_t start = i;
            while (i < len && isalpha(str[i]))
                i++;
            size_t end = i;
            if(end - start == keyword_len && !strncmp(str + start, keyword, keyword_len))
            {
                size_t *pos = malloc(sizeof start);
                if(!pos)
                {
                    printf("malloc failed\n");
                    exit(1);
                }
                *pos = start;
                arrayAddItem(indexes, pos);
            }
        }
    }
    return indexes;
}

int main(void)
{
    dynamic_array *container = findWord("hello world hello", "hello");
    for(size_t i = 0; i < container->size; i++)
    {
        printf("%zu ", *(size_t *) container->array[i]);
        free(container->array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    arrayFree(container);
}
```

and example output:

```
0 12
```